# Flextable not printing correctly when passed to quarto_render() as a parameter

Tags: r, quarto, flextable

I need to pass a flextable object as a paramter to a quarto document in a call to `quarto_render()`.

The flextables I pass in this way are being printed incorrectly - presumably with R's default print method. Instead of a pretty table, I get the output you would expect if you printed a large list.

Flextables defined within the quarto document print as expected, but anything passed via `execute_params` prints incorrectly.

Here's a small reproducible example:

### Quarto document

````
---
title: "Flextable test"
author: "Dave"
format: docx
editor: visual
params:
  my_flextable: "missing"
---

```{r libraries}
library(flextable)
```


## Flextable from this document

Works just fine:

```{r aTableThatWorks}
#| tbl-cap: "working-table"
flextable(head(mtcars))
```

## Flextable from params

Not working:

```{r flextable}
#| tbl-cap: "broken-table"
params[["my_flextable"]]

## I have also tried: -------------------------
# print(params[["my_flextable"]])
# knitr::knit_print(params[["my_flextable"]])
# All to no avail -----------------------------
```
````

#### Passing a flextable as parameter

```r
library(quarto)
library(flextable)

a_flextable <- flextable(mtcars)

quarto_render(input = "R/flextable-test.qmd",
              execute_params = list(my_flextable = a_flextable))
```

#### Rendered output

This is about 500 pages long:

[image: Screencap of word document showing incorrect output]

How can I make flextables passed as parameters print correctly?

Comment: According to the answer by on https://community.rstudio.com/t/param-converted-from-data-frame-to-list/155556 I'm afraid this is not possible when using Quarto.

Comment: You'll create the same exact output but with `params` if you change your call to render it. Instead of calling on `quarto....` use `rmarkdown::render("R/flextable-test.qmd", "word_document", params = list(my_flextable = a_flextable))`. In the QMD, you can just enter `params$my_flextable`. You don't need to quote `a_flextable` in the YAML, either. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks, these are both really helpful. I've opted for passing a the whole dataframe as a parameter, then reconstructing and flextable-ing on the 'quarto side' with `x |> lapply(unlist) |> as.data.frame() |> flextable()`